# how to set scan frame in zbar SDK?

Tags: iphone, camera

I an using Zbar SDK and want to scan QRcode and barcode in my define frame but it is scanning in any part of screen not in my defined frame so where i am doing mistake?
   I want to do scan like this in my defined frame.
      http://www.visionsmarts.com/products/VSBarcodeReader/VSBarcodeReader.html

here is my code.

```
-(void)displayMe{


ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

reader.showsZBarControls=NO;

//////////////black area/////////////////////////

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blackscreen.png"];
UIImageView *imageLogo1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
imageLogo1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

cancelLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,420, 320, 60)];
cancelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100,420, 100, 60)];
[btn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(back) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[cancelLabel bringSubviewToFront:btn];
[imageLogo1 addSubview:cancelLabel];
[imageLogo1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageLogo1 addSubview:btn];
//reader.cameraOverlayView = btn;


///////////////line/////////////////////////////
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ScannerKitLaser@2x.png"];
UIImageView *imageLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageLogo.frame = CGRectMake(40, 240, 230, 10);
[imageLogo1 addSubview:imageLogo];

///////////////Configure reader///////////////////////////////
reader.cameraOverlayView = imageLogo1;

//reader.cameraOverlayView.frame=CGRectMake(40, 240, 230, 30);

//imageLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);


//imageLogo.center = CGRectMake(320/2, 460/2, image.size.width, image.size.height);

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 1];


ZBarCaptureReader *cap=[[ZBarCaptureReader alloc]init];

//cap.scanCrop=CGRectMake(300, 400, 230, 200);

cap.scanCrop=CGRectMake(100, 160, 50,60);
//cap.cameraOverlayView.frame=CGRectMake(40, 240, 230, 30);


[self presentModalViewController: reader
                        animated: YES];
[reader release];
```

Comment: I have a question @Furqi, what does your black screen.png look like by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a UIVIew (e.g. scanView) object and make it as your customize area. Where u want to get scan area there should be transparent area or In image transparent cut.

use this

```
reader.cameraOverlayView = scanView;
```

Also disable to all mode except Portrait mode.

```
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

Full e.g. code

In MyScanCode.h file

```
{ZBarReaderViewController *reader;}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *scanView;
```

In MyScanCode.m file

```
- (void) readCode{
    reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];

    reader.readerDelegate =  self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

    #if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)    
        reader.cameraOverlayView = scanView;
        reader.showsZBarControls = NO;
    #endif

    reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
    [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: can u pls show how this could be done for the landscape orientations,in Ipad?

Comment: reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

and change orientaion according to the view and code into the viewController where u present this ZBar

Comment: when i am doing this i am not getting the full layout.the screen is only half cut both in sides and also bellow?how can i solve that?

Comment: u dont know how to handle Orientations? As same we can do with ZBar. as simple as that. bear in mind this handling will perform on the viewcontroller of class not the view class of the ZBar which u present on model.

Comment: reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||"Right);and also I have a view for that,with a design ,but when runnung it is coming as portrait so the view is not perfect that is my problem

Comment: IT doesn't work for me. The read is being opened full screen, while not starting

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ZBarReaderViewController, try using ZBarReaderView. This worked for me and saved my lot of time. Hope it helps you.

```
ZBarReaderView*reader = [ZBarReaderView new];
ZBarImageScanner * scanner = [ZBarImageScanner new];
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
reader = [reader initWithImageScanner:scanner];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
reader.frame = CGRectMake(20, 126-88, 283, 347);
reader.torchMode = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[reader start];});

[self.view addSubview:reader];
```