# Open zbar scanner in certain part of Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, overlay, zbar

I have a app in which i have implemented Qr code scanning using ZBar.

Now i have also implemented overlay on camera.

The problem is though i have make a overlay, the camera scan whole part of screen.

I want to scan on certain part of screen.

Here is my code,

```
    reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    isCameraStarted = YES;

    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    //Add flash Camera
    if(isTorchOn==NO)
        reader.cameraFlashMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
    else
        reader.cameraFlashMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_NONE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE
                   config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to:1];
    reader.cameraOverlayView = vw;
        reader.showsZBarControls=NO;
    [self presentViewController:reader animated:NO completion:nil];
    [reader release];
```

open the camera in square middle box

Here is the out put i want:

[image]

Comment: There was a similar question asked, and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9937269/908263

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ZBarReaderViewController, try using ZBarReaderView.
Link below worked for me.

```
- (void)startScanning{
NSLog(@"Scanning..");
ZBarReaderView*reader = [ZBarReaderView new];
ZBarImageScanner * scanner = [ZBarImageScanner new];
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
reader = [reader initWithImageScanner:scanner];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
reader.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, [self getWidth]- 20, [self getHeight] -200);
reader.torchMode = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[reader start];});

[self.container addSubview:reader];
}

-(void) readerView:(ZBarReaderView *)readerView didReadSymbols:(ZBarSymbolSet * )symbols fromImage :(UIImage *)image
{
for (ZBarSymbol *sym in symbols)
    {
    NSLog(@"Scanned data: %@", sym.data);
    break;
}
[readerView stop];
// action todo
}
```

Hope helps you.