# ZBar camera overlay always leaves space for controls even if they're not displayed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, zbar-sdk, zbar

I have a QR/bar code reader app that uses the ZBar SDK. I want to implement a custom overlay and remove everything else so the camera view covers the entire screen. The overlay is not difficult to implement. When I remove the ZBar controls via `reader.showsZBarControls = NO;` it removes the controls but leaves a black bar on the bottom of the screen, instead of filling the whole screen with the camera view, which is what I want.

I have tried using `reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;` and `reader.showsCameraControls = NO;` without any luck. Has anyone done anything similar or have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991446/how-to-set-scan-frame-in-zbar-sdk

Comment: @Rushabh Thanks but that only changes the scan area not the whole view area

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference it was as simple as changing the size of the `UIView` in the reader, as such:

```
CGRect frame = reader.readerView.frame;
frame.size.height += 55;
reader.readerView.frame = frame;
```

Maybe it can help someone

Cudos to @iAmbitious for the help